# Google Map Not Working through IP Address

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I am integrating Google Map in my asp.net application. Firstly i will briefly highlight the overall functionality i am trying to achieve.

When a user logins to the site he/she will see the current location loaded in the map on the home page. Upon selection of a particular vehicle through drop down, i need to show the latest location(latitude and Longitude) based on data stored in the database for the selected vehicle on the Map.

I have achieved only the first part i.e loading current location on login. 
It works fine on my localhost,but when i upload the application to my production server to test it by accessing it through IP(both internal and public), the map doesn't load.

I uploaded my application source code on the production server and ran the application. it is working fine, however if i  publish and access it through IP from the server it doesn't load.

I request to help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Krunal. Shaholia

Comment: Can you see any error message in browser console?

Comment: yes i can see 5 errors. It Says that google map's getcurrentposition() and  watchposition functions can be used only with secured origins now. i need to add a SSL Certificate to my application(https).

Answer (score 0):

There is a daily limit, like 2,500, for each IP to get geocode parsed by Google Map. Have you reached that limit by any chance?

Comment: What is your source for this daily limit?

Comment: I just finished a project by using Google Map to parse thousands of geocodes. Once you reached the daily 2,500 limit, you will get a notice from Google saying that you cannot parse more geocode base on your daily quote.

Comment: can you please tell me how to check whether i have reached the daily limit or not. Also as far as I am aware there are very less chances of my application reaching the daily limit.